# Can a vector of a "fixed" size also have a false size (compared to memory size) in c++

Tags: c++, vector

I know that for optimization reasons, the size of a vector might not be the actual size of the object in the memory.
For example, sometimes if I use `push_back` or `resize`, the vector in the memory would actually hold size for twice the number of elements.

I read that this is the case if I push or pop elements from the vector, or use resize, and even that `shrink_to_fit` doesn't always get the vector to the wanted size.

Is it the same way if I don't use all of these? I just initialize a vector of "fixed" number of elements, and never use them.
Can I assume that if I initialize a vector of size 16, it takes out place in memory as 16 * size of the elements?

Thank you.

Edit:

I need the vector for other use. The main problem is that I need to use a specific amount of memory. I can use array, but it would be much less convenient. I'm trying to understand the implementation of a line as:

```
std::vector<X> myVec(16);
```

As I said, I read that if I use push and pop, or resize, the OS (I think) can assign more space than I specified.
But I couldn't find anything that said that about a line as I wrote.

Thank you 2 :)

EDIT 2:

interesting findings:

```
{ 
vector<int> a(16);
vector<int> b(32);
vector<int> c(32);

cout << a.capacity(); // prints 16
cout << b.capacity(); // prints 32

b = a;  // uses vector copy "="
cout << b.capacity(); // prints 32 (!!)


cout << c.capacity(); // prints 32
c = vector<int>(16)  // uses vector move "="
cout << c.capacity(); // prints 16 (!!)}
```

I tried this after reading about the implementation of the move and copy constructors in vectors.

So it looks like when using rvalues (i.e the move constructor), it allocates the specified size. But, when using copy assignment (or when using a copy constructor), it doesn't free the memory, and the vector still has a capacity of 32.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include an example of what you mean by _initialize a vector of "fixed" number of elements_?

Comment: If you don't need any of push_back,... why don't you use std::array?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I think she's asking if the size of vector is actual number of elements. In theory they are thought it's twice as big to keep insertion and deletion amortized complexity at `O(1)`

Comment: FWIW you can use [`capacity()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) to verify how much has been allocated.

Comment: I don't think the standard imposes any limits on the capacity of a vector, other than it must be `>=` the size. That means the answer would be specific to an implementation, and subject to change without warning.

Comment: _I can use array, but it would be much less convenient._ Does this address plain C arrays only or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) as well?

Answer (score 1):

standard does not talk about the initial `capacity` when constructed with the constructor you use and neither for any other constructor:

26.3.11.2 vector constructors, copy, and assignment [vector.cons]

> explicit vector(size_type n, const Allocator& = Allocator()); 
>   Effects: Constructs a vector with n default-inserted elements using
>   the specified allocator.  Requires: T shall be DefaultInsertable into
>   *this.  Complexity: Linear in n.

That said, the result is implementation dependent(so check your compiler).

On the other hand none of the functions you mentioned guarantee the change in `capacity` as you want/expect.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for [`boost::static_vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html). It is initialized at fixed capacity and will never exceed it while allowing to push and pop elements. A sort of `boost::array` but tracking amount of items stored.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `.reserve()` is for. It'll set the capacity to whatever you ask for, even if you're not using it all yet. You'll still get reallocations if you try to `push_back` past that.

Alternatively, create exactly 16 elements to begin with and use as many as you want whenever you want. Though there are no standard guarantees (vectors are not designed for people who are worried about 16 bytes of memory), there's no reason for an implementation to allocate more than that space up-front and I'm not aware of any that do.

Comment: "After reserve(), capacity() is greater or equal to the argument of reserve if
reallocation happens; and equal to the previous value of capacity() otherwise." capacity still can be greater than what expected from reserve

Comment: just wanted to quote from standard. Who cares about 16 bytes these days anyway ;)